# Asynctask Progress bar not displayed properly

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a class in which i have to execute 3 long operations .And have to show the progress bar  at the intervals 25%,50%,75% and 100%.

Since the operations use the UI thread , i cannot place them in the DoinBackground method()..

I am placing the opeartions in progressUpdate method

Code

```
package com.integrated.mpr;

import org.apache.commons.math.linear.RealMatrix;
import org.apache.commons.math.stat.correlation.Covariance;
import org.apache.commons.math.stat.correlation.PearsonsCorrelation;
import org.apache.commons.math.util.FastMath;



public class Logic extends Activity{





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.progress);

        String x = "abc";
        new loadSomeStuff().execute(x);

    }

    public class loadSomeStuff extends AsyncTask<String,Integer,String>{

        ProgressDialog dialog;

        protected void onPreExecute(){

            dialog = new ProgressDialog(Logic.this);
            dialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            dialog.setMax(100);
            dialog.show();

        }



        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            publishProgress(25);

            publishProgress(50);

            publishProgress(75);

            publishProgress(100);
            return null;




        }



        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer...progress){


            if(progress[0]==25){

                dialog.incrementProgressBy(25);
                Log.d("now in ", "25 loop");

                // do some long work in loop1


                dialog.incrementProgressBy(25);
            }

            else if(progress[0]==25){

                dialog.incrementProgressBy(25);
                Log.d("now in ", "50 loop");

                // do some long work in loop2

                dialog.incrementProgressBy(25);
            }

            else if (progress[0] == 75){

                dialog.incrementProgressBy(25);
                // do some long work in loop3

            }
            else{
                dialog.incrementProgressBy(25);
            }
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result){


            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent openList = new Intent("com.integrated.mpr.SENSITIVELIST");
            startActivity(openList);

        }

    }   
}
```

Now , when i run this a blank screen appears , and the progress displays just for 100% .
How can i correct this?? please help

Comment: http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html

Comment: I think my code is principally correct , but plz rectify the error in my code.

Comment: @see and try yourself we are here for refrences and problem solver

Comment: "now in ", "25 loop"<-- are these lines getting logged?

Comment: yeah .. they are getting logged in logcat

Comment: @raju - it is logging in the 25 loop but not the 50 loop wat can be the reason???

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are making some BIG error.

onProgressUpdate is used to update the UI so you have not to do some long work on that method. All the long work you have to made it in doInBackground and when you finish a part of it you can call the onProgressUpdate to update the UI.

Also

> Now , when i run this a blank screen appears , and the progress
>   displays just for 100%

That's because you are doing no work and your phone is fast :P
Try to put a Thread.sleep(1000) betweek each call of onProgressUpdate :)

Than you will replace the sleep with real work!

Comment: To put it simply , u have 4 loops that use the UI thread , I want to display the progress bar at 25%,50%,75%,100 corresponding to that .. how would u do that??

Comment: Please don't rate negative if you don't know what are you talking about. We have just explained your problem, what you have to do and also where are you wrong in your code. You have not to do long work in the UI thread or your apps will be un-responsive and user will complain about it. As I said all the hard work need to be done in doInBackground. Please try to do what I just said. Put a Thread.sleep between the onProgressUpdate calls and you will fake the hardwork and you will understand how it works.

Comment: first of all , i didnot rate u negative , i donot have that much reputation to rate any1 .. yeah m trying the sleep method only

Comment: Also, to understand better how Threading works in Android, I suggest you to read this article: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score -1):

You should not use the ui thread to compute long operation. Your long operations should be executed in doinbackground which will execute them in a different thread.

Edit : I think the problem is that you really want to work with the ui thread for whatever reason you have. If that's the case, maybe a handler would be more suitable.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Comment: that's exactly what he's doing

Comment: that is the problem .. my code is such that i have to use the UI thread for long operations

Comment: No, don't do that. If you do long operation in the ui thread, the activity manager will launch an NRA (non responsive application) dialog box and users will be offered the choice to kill your app.

Comment: Thepoosh > No, he's doing nothing in doinbackground. that's why his app is going from 0 to 100% in no time.

Comment: To put it simply , u have 4 loops that use the UI thread , I want to display the progress bar at 25%,50%,75%,100 corresponding to that .. how would u do that??

Comment: @user1102206 whatever the reason are this is the wrong way to do such thing. As you say (and as we know) long/hard work need to be done in a background thread and not in the UI

Comment: @StErMi > Maybe but we dont know. There are some rare cases where UI has to take the lead (games, video, etc.).